# How to translate this SQL into LINQ, with correlated subquery single table

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

The raw SQL uses correlated subquery for single table, any possibility to translate this with single LINQ Query?

```
SELECT * From dbo.Products AS P1
WHERE SalePrice > (SELECT AVG(SalePrice)
                   FROM dbo.Products AS P2
                   WHERE P1.Type = P2.Type GROUP BY Type)
```

it groups products by type and select the product whose SalePrice is greater than type group average. LINQ data source is a EFCore DbSet.

Comment: try this one https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5282878/How-do-I-convert-SQL-to-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var products = context.Products;

var grouped = 
    from p in products
    group p by p.Type into g
    select new 
    {
        Type = g.Key,
        Average = g.Average(x => x.SalePrice)
    };

var query = 
    from p in products
    join g in grouped on p.Type equals g.Type
    where p.SalePrice > g.Average
    select p;
```

Comment: this does work, but it uses two LINQ query, any way to merge them into one single?

Comment: Don't do that. At the end will be executed only latest combined query. Otherwise LINQ query become a mess.

Comment: Figure it out, but still thanks to provide the inspiration, I go accepting this answer, thanks.  btw do you know how to prevent take all data into memory, when using my single linq? check my anwser.

Comment: As I mentioned before, do not put everything in single query. It is not readable and you can make mistakes as you did in own *answer*.

Comment: Agree now, just wanna give it a try to use single linq. Anyway, thanks for the help again, your way is indeed better.

Answer (score 1):

```
from product in products.AsEnumerable()
group product by product.Type into typeGroup
from product in typeGroup
where product.SalePrice > typeGroup.Average(product => product.SalePrice)
select product;
```

Attention: the product in second from beginning SQL is different from the first.

EF Core 6 could not translate this LINQ on IQueryable

So we use `AsEnumerable()`, and it takes all product data into memory. So maybe the raw SQL one should be better.

Splitting it into two query like another answer will solve the problem and make it more readable.

The reason is `IQueryable.GroupBy()` can't be the final operator for EF 6, which is planned to be improved with EF Core 7.

To prevent `GroupBy()` being the final operator. The solution is:

```
var query =
    from product in products
    join typeGroup in
        from product in products
        group product by product.Type into typeGroup
        select new { Type = typeGroup.Key, Average = typeGroup.Average(p => p.SalePrice) } 
    on product.Type equals typeGroup.Type
    where product.SalePrice > typeGroup.Average
    select product;
```

Comment: So you have created bad query and added `ToArray()`? Nice.